# Rails engine extends config/application.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am in the process of writing a `Rails engine` but i am not sure how to extend my the config/application.rb

I guess i have to get to the application name somehow
any ideas?

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env)

module application_name
  class Application < Rails::Application
  end
end
```

Comment: Could you give an example on what kind of "extension" you're trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

For a --full and --mountable engine

This will be generated for you.

```
module engine_name
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
  end
end
```

In you main applications gemfile add

`gem 'engine_name', path: "/path/to/engine_name"`

And in your applications config/routes.rb file

`mount engine_name::Engine, at: "/<mount_point_you_choose>"`

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html

Taken from the link above...

The --mountable option tells the generator that you want to create a "mountable" and namespace-isolated engine. This generator will provide the same skeleton structure as would the --full option, and will add:

Asset manifest files (application.js and application.css)
A namespaced ApplicationController stub
A namespaced ApplicationHelper stub
A layout view template for the engine
Namespace isolation to config/routes.rb: